# NiftyReg reg_resample results in strange artifacts when registering MNI-ICBM-152 atlas

Tags: neuroimaging

I'm using NiftyReg for image registration, and I have several artifacts when applying the warp from a non-linear registering of de facto standard [MNI-ICBM-152](http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/ServicesAtlases/ICBM152NLin2009) atlas.

Here are a few slices showing the artifacts:

[image: First slice] [image: Slice 55] [image: Slice 100]

I tested the registration to the the [GG-366-0.7mm](https://brainder.org/download/flair/) T1 atlas (after skull-stripping with BET from FSL)
Here are the commands I ran:

```
reg_f3d -ref GG-366-T1-0.7mm.brain.nii.gz -flo MNI-ICBM-152-T1.brain.nii.gz -res MNI-ICBM-152-T1.nlin-GG.nii.gz -cpp MNI-ICBM-152-T1.nlin-GG.cpp.nii.gz
reg_resample -ref GG-366-T1-0.7mm.brain.nii.gz -flo MNI-ICBM-152-WM.nii.gz -trans MNI-ICBM-152-WM.nlin-GG.cpp.nii.gz
```

This is using the latest git version of Nifty-Reg. Using the latest stable version (1.3.9) the result is the same, but the reg_resample program takes the -cpp parameter instead of -trans.

Any ideas if this is a bug in Nifty-Reg or can be worked-around?